# search query slow, recordset based on view. how to speed it up?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a recordset based on a view in MySQL that I use to return search results but it is painfuilly slow (consistently 21 seconds!).  A similar search in the same environment takes under a second.

I fear that it is the view that is slowing things down since I have four left joins and one subquery in there to make related data available in the search.

Is there any general guidance for speeding up a query when using a view?  I have researched indexing but it seems that is not allowed in MySQL in views.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

The code to create my view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW vproducts2 AS  
SELECT products2.productid, products2.active, products2.brandid,
    products2.createddate, products2.description, products2.inventorynum,
    products2.onhold, products2.price, products2.refmodnum, products2.retail,
    products2.sefurl, products2.series, products2.sold,
    `producttype`.`type` AS type, categories.category AS category,  
    `watchbrands`.`brand` AS brand, productfeatures.productfeaturevalue AS size,  
    (SELECT productimages.image
        FROM productimages
        WHERE productimages.productid = products2.productid
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS pimage  
FROM products2  
    LEFT JOIN producttype ON producttype.typeid = products2.typeid  
    LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.categoryid = products2.categoryid  
    LEFT JOIN watchbrands ON watchbrands.brandid = products2.brandid  
    LEFT JOIN productfeatures ON productfeatures.productid = products2.productid
        AND productfeatures.featureid = 1
```

Comment: can we have a look at your query please?

Comment: MySQL views it's not a good deal - reconsider rewrite your app and remove all possible views. I've tried almost everthing found Google too speed up my app and take this radical and efficient solution

Comment: You want to optimize the indexes that participate in your view. You can't add indexes to the view but you can to the underlying tables that the view is based on.

Comment: Views shouldn't slow things down unless you're doing a lot of joining or complex SQL statements.  Views do not occupy space so they're usually quick as they act as more of a map than anything else.  If you build indexes on the table itself, it will speed up the view.

Comment: @AllysondePaula You should have asked here, not google :) Views are a good thing and shouldn't be avoided per se.

Comment: @AllysondePaula - advising against views while having literally close to no knowledge about them is a bad thing to do, wouldn't you agree? :) So to rephrase your comment - Views are a good idea. But like all good ideas, it has to be used properly.

Comment: As for the actual problem, your view is slow and will be slow no matter what you do because of the subquery. Rewrite your subquery into a join and your view will be as fast as the raw query you posted. Naturally, if the query is slow - view will be as well so use `EXPLAIN` to see what's happening and index as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have indexes on the *underlying* tables, not on the view. The view should use such tables.

The first index that screams out is on `productimages(productid, productimage)`.  This will speed up the subquery in the `select` clause.

You should also have primary key indexes for what look like primary keys on all the tables . . . `categories(categoryid)`, `producttype(typeid)`, `watchbrands(brandid)`, and (I think) productfeatures(productid, featureid).

Comment: Thanks so much for the specificity in your response.  I created indexes in the products table with no noticable difference.  I will create indexes through the phpMyAdmin console for the other related fields.  I thought the indexed fields were viewable in the console but in the latest version of the console my host has I do not see the indexed fields.

Comment: Wow - what a difference a little indexing will do!  I was trying to figure out indexing on the view but doing it on the related tables took the search from 21 seconds to 1 second.  It all works perfectly now.  Thanks to all who took the time to chime in and Gordon for your specific guide to reassure me which fields to index.